# Conexões múltiplas de banco de dados do codeigniter

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, conexão

Estive investigando o uso de múltiplos bancos de dados com CodeIgniter. Se eu sei quais são os bancos de dados antes do tempo, eu posso definir as informações no arquivo de configuração e, em seguida, chamar o grupo de banco de dados que eu preciso.

Na minha situação, no entanto, eu preciso armazenar essas informações de banco de dados em outro banco de dados. É uma espécie de banco de dados mestre com informações gerais sobre um cliente, incluindo o banco de dados e as credenciais em que os dados do cliente estão armazenados. Esse fornecedor pode então adicionar clientes sempre que quiser e ter segregados os dados de cada cliente em diferentes bancos de dados.

Como posso configurar o banco de dados e as credenciais com base nos valores que recebo do banco de dados mestre em CodeIgniter, ou existe mesmo uma maneira de fazer isso?

Preciso disto porque tenho um sistema único e cada cliente que se loga tem um banco de dados único para ele, então imagine que poderei ter 5 pessoas utilizando o sistema ao mesmo tempo mas cada uma delas acessando o seu próprio banco de dados.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Abs

Answer (score 2):

Em geral você tem apenas 1 banco de dados configurado no arquivo `/application/config/database.php` do CodeIgniter e que por padrão a configuração se chama `default`:

```
// Isto já existe
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '80.45.168.49',
    'username' => 'steven.douglas',
    'password' => 'hEo&73T#@wToh',
    'database' => 'main_db',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Você vai precisar configurar uma outra logo após, e nomeá-la, por exemplo, `auxiliar`:

```
// Isto terá que ser adicionado
$db['auxiliar'] = array(
    'dsn'      => '',
    'hostname' => '80.45.168.50',
    'username' => 'john.eastwood',
    'password' => 'cEsl#$tAnw4Mh',
    'database' => 'another_bd',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt'  => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

E observando a classe MY_Model, que se chama assim justamente porque é para que você a personalize, você vê que a configuração `default` é associada a variável `$db`. Então você terá que criar uma variável como `$db2`, ou um nome de sua preferência, para sua configuração do `auxiliar`, editando o arquivo `/application/core/MY_Model.php`:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    protected $active_group;
    protected $db2; // <------ ADICIONE 

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    public function connect($active_group = 'default'){
        $this->active_group = $active_group;
        $db = $this->load->database($active_group, TRUE);
        $this->db = $db;

        // ADICIONE ISTO ABAIXO
        $db2 = $this->load->database('auxiliar', TRUE);
        $this->db2 = $db2;
    }

}
```

Pronto! agora você pode usar `$this->db2` no seus *models*:

```
$query = $this->db2->select('nome_pessoa, numero_cpf')->get('pessoas');
```

Comment: Olá C. Bohok, primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. Tinha pensando nesta solução o problema é que esta conexão DB2 ela troca conforme o usuário que estiver logado, ou seja, se for o usuário A1 por exemplo ele a BD2 deverá conectar no banco BD1, se for o usuário A2 a conexão DB2 deverá conectar no banco DB2, e assim por diante. É esta conexào do DB2 que precisa ser dinâmica dependendo do usuário que estiver conectado no sistema naquele momento, esta sua solução até funciona mas ela não é dinâmica no segunda banco de dados

Answer (score 1):

Para funcionar como o [C. Bohok](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/20804/c-bohok) disse, é necessário que o seu model extenda de `MY_Model` ao invés de extender do `CI_Model`

Estou usando o CodeIgniter3

Originalmente seu model deve ser algo como isso:

```
class Assuntos_model extends CI_Model{
```

Altere para:

```
class Assuntos_model extends MY_Model{
```